# Duplicate class found when same class name under test and androidTest

Tags: java, classloader

I am facing a problem I have no idea how to solve. Here is part of the project structure

```
+-- com.packagename.appname (test)
|   +-- db
|       +-- ClassATest.java
+-- com.packagename.appname (androidTest)
|   +-- db
|       +-- ClassATest.java
```

As you can see there are two `ClassATest.java`. The one under `androidTest` is where I test several stuff using the real db which depends on the application `context`. Now, under `test` I would like to test some other stuff mocking such database connection.

My problem is that as soon as I created `ClassATest.java` under `test` I got this error:

```
Duplicate class found in the file 'absolute-path-of-ClassATest.java'
```

Is there a way to prevent this error?

**UPDATE**

It's not really a need to keep the same name. In fact I have already changed both names: `ClassATest` (under `test`) and `ClassAATest` (under `androidTest`).

But I would like to now a more elegant way to solve this issue, if there is any.

Comment: why do you need to use identical class names?

Comment: Well you could pick a better name, like `ClassAUnitTest` and `ClassAIntegrationTest`.

Comment: The point is that unit test and integration test do not collide for any reason, because they will not be executed together. And both tests run fine, outside of Android Studio.  It's only reported by Android Studio

Comment: I have a use case for this. If you have util classes that you use in both androidTest and test, it makes sense to give them the same name, if they are the same. You could use symlinks to create a copy of one into the other test hierarchy. A solution would be to define these classes in your main hierarchy, but then you get test-related code in your app. I don't see why Android Studio should not allow me to use the same names in two versions of tests.

Comment: Since this is an error message of the *compiler*, the tag `[classloader]` is inappropriate. Instead, you should have tagged the question with the name of the IDE, as depending on the IDE, there is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have 2 classes with the same name in the same class loader. The test for `FooTest` should be named `FooTestTest`.